# Protractor - Okta - Time out waiting for Angular page after okta login

Tags: angular, protractor, jhipster, okta

I'm trying to automate protractor UI tests for an angular5 website that uses Okta for authentication.  When you navigate to our site, if you haven't logged into Okta, it will redirect to Okta first, then back to our page.

My test looks like this:

```
    fit('My Test', () => {

        //OKTA part
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get('/');  //this will automatically redirect me to Okta
        signInPage.setUserName('MyUserName');
        signInPage.setPassword('MyPassword');
        element(by.css('[data-se-for-name="remember"]')).click();
        signInPage.login();
        //Okta part done.

        //Navigating back to Angular 5
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        browser.get('/municipality/add');  //This should be an Angular 5 page
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css('[ng-reflect-name="muncplName"]')).sendKeys("asdf");
 });
```

but this fails when I try to run it.

It says:

> Message:
>       Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 20 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an
>   Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details:
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>       While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, [ng-reflect-name="muncplName"])

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using JHipster? The reason I ask is because it has e2e tests that log in for you.

Comment: @MattRaible, sort of.  The bulk of our project is using Jhipster... but the authentication piece was a custom job.